# Removing lines from file matching 2 strings

Tags: regular-expression, perl

I am trying to remove lines in a file that contain 2 strings.
I am using:

```
perl -i.tmp -ne "print unless /$STRING_A/ and /$STRING_B/" /foo/bar/file.txt
```

The result is that all lines from the file containing `$STRING_A` are deleted regardless if `$STRING_B` is also in the same line.
What is the problem here? How can I fix this?

Comment: @Inian:I want to delete the lines that contain **both** these strings in the line

Comment: Have you consider adding parentheses?  `and` has a very low priority.

Comment: @SatōKatsura: Where should the parenthesis be?

Comment: `perl -lne 'print unless (/foo/o and /bar/o)'`

Comment: I tested this `perl` command with and without parenthesis and it worked just fine. @Jim, could you provide an example where it didn't work?

Comment: Sounds your `$STRING_B` is empty/not set. Check if that has any value.

Comment: @SatōKatsura:Yes that worked!